# SQL Server browser shows databases that don't seem to exist

Tags: sql-server

On a client server with a SQL Server database, I opened SSMS and browsed for more / Database Engine. In the list were several databases that matched server names (as expected). Remoteing to the server indicated showed NO SQL Server running on that server. So.....is it a zombie or is it fibbing me in the name and if so how do I find it? I don't have permissions to open it in SSMS, which could mean either zombie or it's named like a server it's not really on. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: there might be multiple instance running on the server. Try check `Admin Tools` - `Services`

Comment: Services is how I found out there wasn't any sqlserver on the ones reported. There was an instance of Microsoft Internal Server but no SQLBrowser service and documentation says that MIS will not report nor be connected too from outside the host machine.  Also there are multiple instances on one server and it's correctly showing both.